# What is a good way to handle loading multiple content, in the LoadContent() method/function

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

So I know it is bad to load content on constructor calls but is it ok to call a .load function for a class from the LoadContent()? 
ex.

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    viewport = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
    player1.load(spriteBatch, Content);
}
```

Within the .load I would have `Texture2D  playerT = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");`

Is that ok? or what is the best way to handle multiple content that needs to be loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with loading things in a constructor call is that your likely going to want to unload content at times to save memory but keep an instance of the class around that way the class is ready to be used again by simply calling load(). So loading any time after the Game class initializes itself is fine and should be done based upon when the content is needed not a design convention.

So anytime past Game.Init is fine. And if the player class needs content right off the bat then calling load inside LoadContent() is the best place to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure if it was ok or not to load content later. Most of the examples and tutorals seem to want to have you load everything at the beginning. If calling it later should it get called from the update i guess?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding "multiple content":

A subclass of the `Game` class inherits a `ContentManager` object called `Content`.

However, you're not limited to only this one `ContentManager` object (in fact you don't even have to use it at all). You can make as many as you need and put them anywhere you want. This is one way to handle differing content on different "screens" and such, so that you can load and UNload the pieces you need to.

To set up a different content manager in a different screen, you could do the following:

In a class somewhere, make a variable:

```
ContentManager moreContent;
```

Then initialize it like follows:

```
moreContent = new ContentManager(game.Services);
moreContent.RootDirectory = game.Content.RootDirectory;
```

You will have to pass your `Game` object into the class in order to initialize it properly. This will make this content manager have the same root folder as the parent `Game.Content`. Of course you can change this to whatever you like.

Now for this screen only, you can do stuff like:

```
Texture2D playerT = moreContent.Load<Texture2D>("player");
```

And then if you switch screens (on `Update`):

```
moreContent.Unload();
```

will take all the screen's content out of memory.